JS Funcion async que retorne valor y se asigne a una variable
const dashboard = (() => {

async function setLabelDash() {

    const result = await axios.get(BASE_URL + "/DashboardConstroller/listaGastosAnuales")
    return result.data.lista;
}
let instance = {
    setLabelDash
}

return instance;
  })();


 let conste = dashboard.setLabelDash();
 console.log(conste);

Porque no me devuelve mi valor que necesito y tan solo me retorna de nuevo la promesa
El valor que tengo que mostrar es un array y esa variable conste, la usare en una nueva clase de ChartJS

La funcion setLabelDash es asíncrona, por tanto el console.log se va a ejecutar antes de que que finalice la función. Si quieres comprobar el valor pon el console.log dentro de un timeout de 2 o 3 segundos o dentro de una funcion asincrona para ponerle un await a let conste = dashboard.setLableDash(). Pero la variable tiene el valor correcto, lo unico es que cuando se imprime en pantalla aun no terminó la promesa
